# Matplotlib import Error: ValueError: Key grid.color: '"' does not look like a color arg

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I  am getting following error while importing matplotlib

```
import matplotlib
  warnings.warn("loaded more than 1 DLL from .libs:"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 876, in <module>
    rcParamsDefault = _rc_params_in_file(
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 810, in _rc_params_in_file
    config[key] = val  # try to convert to proper type or raise
  File "C:\Users\xx\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 646, in __setitem__
    raise ValueError(f"Key {key}: {ve}") from None
ValueError: Key grid.color: '"' does not look like a color arg
```

Versions

- Python-3.8.13
- matplotlib-3.6.0

Please let me know if any solution for this problem.

Comment: `pip uninstall matplotlib` followed by `pip install matplotlib`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm hitting the same issue downgraded to 3.5.1 and worked..but there's got to be a better solution

Comment: solved for me as well, but anyone knows why versions above 3.5.1 have this problem or why 3.5.1 solves it?

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this error myself.

The [documentation for the matplotlibrc file](https://matplotlib.org/stable/users/explain/customizing.html#the-default-matplotlibrc-file) states:

> Colors: for the color values below, you can either use ...
> - a double-quoted hex string, such as "#ff00ff".
> The unquoted string ff00ff is also supported for backward
> compatibility, but is discouraged.

It would appear the quotation marks are required to escape the preceding # of the hex string from being misinterpreted as a comment, however the quotation marks are then not being parsed properly downstream.

Regardless, one can still use the "unquoted string" example they provide (i.e. no quotes and no preceding #) if downgrading matplotlib is not a desirable option.